# Merge two `data.table` objects

Tags: r, statistics, data.table

I have two data sets and I want to map the second data set to the first one:

```
n <- c(2, 3, 5,6,7,8) 
s <- c("aa", "bb", "cc","aa", "bb", "cc") 
b <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
df <- data.table(n, s, b) 

rs <- c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
replace1 <- c("Product 1", "Product 2", "Product 3") 
replace2 <- c("Customer 1", "Customer 2", "Customer 3") 

df.replace <- data.table(rs, replace1, replace2)
```

So Basically if in `df` is an `aa`, I want to add a column with `Product 1` and `Customer 1`.

Furthermore, I am also using the `data.table` package for speed, because my files are greater than 2 GB each. Either the mapping files and also the file that I have to map the values to.

Any recommendations how to implement this in R?

**Update**

My desired output:

[image]

Comment: How would your desired output will look like?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thx for your answer! Please have a look at my uploaded picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `data.table`s binary join to do a **right join**

```
setkey(df, s) # key `df` by `s`
(Res <- df[df.replace]) # Perform the binary join
#    n  s     b  replace1   replace2
# 1: 2 aa  TRUE Product 1 Customer 1
# 2: 6 aa FALSE Product 1 Customer 1
# 3: 3 bb FALSE Product 2 Customer 2
# 4: 7 bb  TRUE Product 2 Customer 2
# 5: 5 cc  TRUE Product 3 Customer 3
# 6: 8 cc FALSE Product 3 Customer 3
```

---

**Edit**

Or (per your comment) you can also do a **left join** with binary join

```
setkey(df.replace, rs) # key `df.replace` by `rs`
setkey(df, s) # key `df` by `s`
(Res <- df.replace[df])
#    rs  replace1   replace2 n     b
# 1: aa Product 1 Customer 1 2  TRUE
# 2: aa Product 1 Customer 1 6 FALSE
# 3: bb Product 2 Customer 2 3 FALSE
# 4: bb Product 2 Customer 2 7  TRUE
# 5: cc Product 3 Customer 3 5  TRUE
# 6: cc Product 3 Customer 3 8 FALSE
```

With this join, if you have values in `df.replace` that don't match, it won't remove the rows from `df` and assign `NA`s to the relevant columns

---

Even better option (if you don't have too many columns in `df.replace`) is to assign these values by reference to `df`. This way, you won't need to save the results anywhere, and `df` would be updated by itself.

```
setkey(df, s) # key `df` by `s`
df[df.replace, 
         `:=`(replace1 = replace1, 
              replace2 = replace2)
   ] # Perform the binary join and save results in `df`
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! The onliest problem is that if there is no match in the df.replace the row get`s deleted, however, I would like to get a NA or sth like that? Any recommendation how to do that with data.tables?